# Console doesn't open automatically

Tags: boot, command-line

After Ubuntu installation I enabled system boot in a console mode using the following command:

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

It have always worked fine but yesterday console stopped to appear after reboot on its own so now I have to press CTRL+ALT+F1 each time. I didn't do any changes it simply stopped to work all of sudden.

Any ideas what could happen? How can I make console to start automatically?

Actually there was one change but it wasn't related to settings. When I installed Ubuntu initially I used VGA port, after that I have been using the system in a headless mode for a long time and now connected computer to monitor via HDMI. Not sure if it makes any difference. I can't connect it via VGA again to check.